# change width of NeWindow using react-new-window react

Tags: reactjs, npm, window

I'm using this plugin:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-new-window

The new window opens up but I cannot change the width. When I use

```
 <NewWindow features={{ width: "380" }} title="Clipify music player">
```

It actually makes the window bigger, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have to provide both width and height to make it work.

```js
<NewWindow features={{ width: 380, height: 380 }} title="Clipify music player">
```

Also, I think it's more sure to pass `width` and `height` as integer instead of string

Hope it helps

Comment: it worked but I want the height to auto fit the content, not be fixed.

Comment: I think this is the way it works. A warning appears in the chrome console telling `width` and `height` must be provided when the `center` prop is provided. The library defaults the `center` prop as `parent`. This property seems to be required